# How to output Debug level log messages to Application Insights in production

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-application-insights

A simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application, deployed in azure as an app service - edited to make sure the configurations are the same for ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT development and production.

with the following in the Configure method of the Startup class:

`loggerFactory.AddApplicationInsights(app.ApplicationServices, LogLevel.Debug);`

results in different behavior depending on the value of ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

Using basic ASP.NET core logging, with Application insights configured I get the following behaviour:

**With ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT == development**

LogDebug messages appear as trace messages in the Azure Portal Live Metrics Stream. However none of the applications messages seem to persist - they cant be queried through visual studio or analytics.applicationinsights.io

**With ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT == production**

LogDebug messages DO NOT appear as trace messages in the Azure Portal Live Metrics Stream. The applications messages at level Information or above are persisted - they can be queried through visual studio or analytics.applicationinsights.io

Does anyone know how to get debug level messages to appear in the case ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT == production ?

Maybe my google fu is weak, but I can't find any relevant documentation on this.

Answer (score 2):

Add below code into your appsettings.json:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable does not control the logger behavior. Need some more info to understand why you are encountering this behavior.
See this:
https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-aspnetcore/issues/688